# Issues with fstack-protector?

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

I want to detect stack overflow or corruption in my code. Hence, i wrote a small program where stack overflow is simulated. I compiled it using the command:

```
gcc overflow.c -g -fstack-protector-all
```

However, upon executing the binary i got segmentation fault but no other information.
Can anybody please help me where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `ulimit -c` is set to a value much bigger than zero, a core dump named `core` is written; you can see the backtrace via running `gdb program core` and then typing `backtrace` at the prompt.

Comment: I did it. but the information i got is no different from the one which i compiled like : gcc overflow.c                                     My Q is what exactly does the compiling option -fstack-protector-all make difference?